# UMLet Bold Face Single Word

Tags: uml, tool-uml, umlet

I need to figure out if there is a way in UMLet to apply boldfacing to a single word without imposing a line break. For example:

read(**out** value)

I don't see any way to do this. Does anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To create a bold words just use

```
**words that should be bold**
```

For more information check out:

http://sourceforge.net/p/umlettosourceco/discussion/markdown_syntax

So in your example

```
read(**out** value)
```

Comment: Solution not working, neither does what is written in the link?

Comment: This answer works for me in Umlet version 14.3.0. Even just one asterix works.

Answer (score 0):

For now (UMLet 14.2) it isn't possible to format a single word.

The implementation is looking for formating markups at start and end of the text (line).

https://github.com/umlet/umlet/blob/14a41c6ba3bc616ed5078357b532deb938bab837/umlet-elements/src/main/java/com/baselet/control/StringStyle.java#L48